# Porting Java OpenGL-based Android game to iOS (no native code)

Tags: java, android, ios, mobile, porting

I might be a little screwed here. I've been developing an engine for use in various games that I've been making for a long time now.

The engine is written in 100% Java(no NDK), and uses OpenGL ES 1x for rendering. its got textures, 3d mesh loading, animation, image based fonts, tilemaps, custom file types, and all that good stuff at around 8.5k lines of code, so you can probably see why I wouldn't want to recreate all that on iOS :(

Anyways, some of the engine relies on the Android SDK, but those parts can easily be removed/changed, leaving just the engine code and calls to opengl. However, never having developed anything on iOS before, I am a little clueless as to where I should begin with the porting.

I know that you need to develop using XCode(or is it objective-c?) on iOS, but would it be possible to use Java instead?

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could just point me in the right direction. It would really suck to have to rewrite my entire engine in a different language.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to compile java code  so it can run on ios ,and propably will not be in the future either because of the nature of the ios witch is a close platform .

Your best choise here is to rewrite your code to c  witch i think its not very difficult   since opengl commands stays the same  plus you will see a performance boost